# Unable to download an existing file with wget and python http server

Tags: python, wget, simplehttpserver

so I mounted an http server with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` I get:

`Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...`
But when I try to download with

```
wget http://192.168.100.65:8000/tmp/postgres_default_pass.txt
```

I got:

```
    192.168.100.74 - - [09/Sep/2020 23:32:30] code 404, message File not found
192.168.100.74 - - [09/Sep/2020 23:32:30] "GET /tmp/postgres_default_pass.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

In the wget machine:

```
    Connecting to 192.168.100.65:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 File not found
2020-09-09 23:32:31 ERROR 404: File not found.
```

But the file exists, doing an ls I can find the file.

```
 ls
hsperfdata_kali
postgres_default_pass.txt
sqlmaprgl22hl623598
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleHTTPServer serves relative to its current directory. Try `wget http://localhost:8000/postgres_default_pass.txt`

That being said, please do note that in python3 it has been moved into http as http.server. python2.7 is officially unsupported so it's probably a good idea to move any systems over to python3.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem, and I will do that.